# Eureka registration with specifc hostname / ip

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I would like to register my service with the Eureka server, using a specific Hostname or IP.

This is my configuration snippet:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    hostname: localhost
    ipAddr: 127.0.0.1
```

I am using the 2.0.2.RELEASE version of client.

I would expect the service to register with 127.0.0.1; if I switch `preferIpAddress` to false, I would expect it to register with `localhost`.

Instead, I always get this:

> APPLICATION/1H1DNQ2.mshome.net:application:8080 -
>   Re-registering apps/APPLICATION

`1H1DNQ2` is my PC id. I also tried using `eureka.hostname`, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to identify with the hostname of my choice using this snippet:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    client:
      hostname: localhost
```

I found the inspiration on [this](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/tag/eureka/) article.

I think this is sort of a workaround though and I am still looking for a more specific solution.